# Spring Security LDAP: Bind vs. Authenticate against Active Directory in ApacheDS

Tags: active-directory, apacheds, spring-security-ldap

### What works

I developed this against our company's AD:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider adProvider() {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(
            adConfig.getDomain(), adConfig.getUrl(), adConfig.getRootDn());

    adProvider.setSearchFilter(adConfig.getSearchFilter());
    adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
    adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    adProvider.setAuthoritiesMapper(authorities -> List.of(new FooAuthority("*")));

    return adProvider;
}
```

This does work; I can log in using my company credentials. **Important**: I can use my `sAMAccountName` (which happens to be my `uid` as well) to log in.

### Goal

Now I want to have some automated tests for certain edge cases, using a local AD. I chose ApacheDS for its cross platform availability, plus it has some Docker containers available. I use [openmicroscopy/apacheds](https://hub.docker.com/r/openmicroscopy/apacheds/)
, because it seemed active, documented and configurable, important for a rookie like me.

### Problem

The problem is, I cannot log in. I traced it down to two lines in `o.s.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`: while `searchForUser(ctx, username)` in `doAuthentication(...)` (line 148 in 5.0.12.RELEASE) works with my `sAMAccountName` (like *foobar*), `contextFactory.createContext(env)` in `bindAsUser(...)` (line 204 in 5.0.12.RELEASE) requires a fully qualified DN (like *cn=foobar,ou=people,dc=acme,dc=com*) to work.

So it seems there is some misconfiguration on my side, probably because of my misunderstanding... Seems I do need some different user to authenticate than to search afterwards? How do I configure this, and/but why does our company's AD works just fine? PS: I read about anonymous authentication, maybe our company allows such? But using Apache Directory Studio against the company's AD requires me to log in (as far as I can tell)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP based simple BIND operation always requires the distinguished name (DN) of the entry and  password. Only AD allows to perform the BIND operation with samAccountName. AD is somewhat special.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Do you have an URL to any kind of documentation about that? I'm asking because I'd like to do some research on how to configure or how to work around that, and need some keywords ;-)

Comment: Of course the ultimate source would be the RFC (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4511#section-4.2).

Comment: Thanks again. For future reference: `The Bind request is defined as follows:

        BindRequest ::= [APPLICATION 0] SEQUENCE {
             version                 INTEGER (1 ..  127),
             name                    LDAPDN,
             authentication          AuthenticationChoice }`